# How can I get selenium to click on hdmi output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

My script is all done and ready to go to watch tv shows on auto pilot and runs perfectly on my computer. The issue I'm having now which is odd because some clicks do work by finding element by link text but the other clicks will not work on the tv here is the code.

```
eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('PLAY NOW')

action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(eleml,200,200)
action.click()
action.perform()

import time
time.sleep(10)

action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(eleml,200,200)
action.click()
action.perform()

action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(eleml,200,200)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

Now I figured maybe the clicks are basing the pixels off the tv screen instead of the computer screen, so I increased it to `600, 600` but it still didn't work.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code of the element containing the `PLAY NOW` link text? Also, could it be that this element is inside an iframe (pretty common for players)?

Comment: <a rel="nofollow" href="http://putlocker.is/hdvideo/hdstream.php?        movie=That '70s Show Season 5 Episode 1: Going to California (2002)"         title="Watch That '70s Show Season 5 Episode 1: Going to California         (2002) in HD" style="color:#ffffff;" class="movgr">PLAY NOW</a>        this is the code here for the html. And the player itself is flash and this is why I have to use a series of clicks because I cannot get the play button or full screen button on its own,

Comment: What about the iframes?

Comment: too be honest I don't really know much about iframes and had to google just to see what it was lol. Here is a link to the website I've been using as a sample for the project  http://putlocker.is/watch-that-70s-show-tvshow-season-5-episode-1-online-free-putlocker.html

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like a timing issue. [Wait for the link to be clickable](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "PLAY NOW"))
)
element.click()
```

Comment: Could it be a timing issue though? It runs perfectly fine on my laptop but as soon as it is plugged into the tv the other clicks won't work. Even if one click were off then the video would still atleast full screen,  it is hard to believe that if all 3 clicks were off that it still wouldn't play the video or at least show some sort of action aha.  I will try and maybe delay the clicks by a few more seconds and see what happens.

Comment: I'm not getting anymore errors, I have delayed the first click on the video player by 20 more seconds and it solved the issue i was having.

Comment: @koopakid that's what I tried to help u avoid, it is not recommended to have this sort of hardcoded delays and instead wait for the element explicitly via the `WebDriverWait`.